# Passing array data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

Page 1 (index.php)

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) { ?>
<select id="name[<?php echo $i;?>]">
<option value="John">John</option>
<option value="Alice">Alice</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="name-id">

<input type="text" id="location">

<?php } ?>
</table>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/function.js"></script>
```

Page 2 (function.js)

```
for (i=0;i<2;i++){
$('select#name['+i+']').on('change',function()
{ alert(1); } ); }
```

The Code is not working after i add in the array.. Someone please help me..

Comment: Your are generating invalid markup, IDs are supposed to be _unique_.

Comment: How to do if i want to add another 5 same drop down menu in the same page? if without array

Comment: in the name is where you add the bracket to build an array `<input name="some_name[]" >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the `[]` in the id, but rather do that, you'd better not introduce `[]` in id, the `[]` should be used in `name` attribute in common usage.

html:

```
<select id="name_<?php echo $i;?>" name="name[]">
```

js:

```
$('select#name_'+i).on('change',function() { //...
```

Or you could add a class and use class selector instead of id selector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `[]` in id

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    $('#name\\[' + i + '\\]').on('change', function () {
        alert(1);
    });
}
```

also since id should be unique in a page there is no need for the element selector `select`

---

But I would recommend adding a class to select the similar select elements instead of using id

```
<select id="name[<?php echo $i;?>]" class="name">
    <option value="John">John</option>
    <option value="Alice">Alice</option>
</select>
```

then

```
$('select.name').on('change', function () {
    alert(1);
});
```

---

Comment: is working...Thanks..

        var name=new Array(); 
 name[i]= $('select#name\\[' + i + '\\]').val();

is it correct for this?

Comment: @user2892997 `name[i]= $('select#name\\[' + i + '\\]').val();` - you need to use `\\` not `\`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `[` AND `]` with `\\` in front.

```
$('#name\\[' + i + '\\]').on('change', function () {
    alert(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a bad idea to make identifiers look like an array.
Maybe you can use 'data' attribute?

I edited your code a little:

**HTML**

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) { ?>
<select id="name" data-index="[<?php echo $i;?>]">
    <option value="John">John</option>
    <option value="Alice">Alice</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="name-id">

<input type="text" id="location">

<?php } ?>
```

**JS**

```
    $('body').on('change',"select#name", function () {
        alert($(this).data("index"));
    });
```